# How can I understand which condition fails?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
SET t1.col3 = "something"
WHERE t1.col4 = t2.col3 AND
      t1.col5 IS NOT NULL
```

Sometimes one of those conditions on the `WHERE` clause is `FALSE` and then nothing updates. I'm trying to understand why nothing updates? I mean I want to set an error for each condition to specify me which condition is `FALSE`.

I'm not sure but maybe using `@variable` or using `CASE WHEN` would be a approach. Is there any solution?

---

My query in reality:

```
UPDATE
     qanda AS ans1
JOIN qanda AS ans2 ON ans2.related = ans1.related
JOIN qanda AS ques ON ans2.related = ques.id
SET ans1.acceptedanswer = IF( ans1.id <> ?, 0, IFNULL( ans1.acceptedanswer, 0 ) ^ b'1' ),
ans1.aadate = IF( ans1.id <> ?, ans1.aadate, ?)                                                             
WHERE ques.author_id = ?
  AND ans2.id = ?
  AND ans2.author_id = ? 
  AND (ques.amount IS NULL or ans1.acceptedanswer IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what would you like to get as an output? What is half of the records have `col5 is null` and the other half fails on the first condition?

Comment: @sagi If something get update, then I don't need to get anything. But if update fails (nothing update). then I need to know why it fails?

Comment: Just manually select the join of the update with one of the conditions, you will see if there are records to update.

Comment: @sagi In reality I have a website like SO, and query above accepts accepted-answer. Now I need to check some conditions before updating. For example: the time user can accept an answer as accepted after 20 min. and some other conditions. Now I'm trying to manage those errors.

Comment: Can you use the proper names for your tables and columns please, if those are real, then you need to be descriptive in your naming.

Comment: @PaulStanley I added my real query.

Comment: Are you really complaining that mysql wont update for a WHERE condition when it s not satisfied?

Comment: Note that in mysql if column values don't change it will report no rows updated, even though the where clause matches some rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `SELECT` and `CASE` to print failed condition as bellow:

```
SELECT
CASE 
   WHEN (t1.col4 = t2.col3) = FALSE THEN 'FAILED condition: t1.col4 = t2.col3'
   WHEN (t1.col5 IS NOT NULL) = FALSE THEN 'FAILED condition: t1.col5 IS NOT NULL'
END
 FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
SET t1.col3 = "something"
WHERE (t1.col4 = t2.col3 AND
      t1.col5 IS NOT NULL) = FALSE
```

**EDIT:** `UPDATE` returns the number of rows that were actually changed See [MySql ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).
So you need to run it in different call.

**N.B.** I didn't run it; just tried to share a concept.

Comment: I'm not sure it works or not, but if it works, it is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: However your query is incomplete. Where is `UPDATE` clause?

Comment: I didnt run it. But it should work. Please run it (may be few syntax correction needed) and feedback

Comment: here ``UPDATE`` is missing because it's just to test  failed conditions(So no update operation)

Comment: Well I've tested .. it works (it returns correct message). How can I implement that for `update` clause?

Comment: **UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed** ref :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html   So you need to run it in different call.

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
SET t1.col3 = "something"
WHERE t1.col4 = t2.col3 AND
      t1.col5 `IS` NOT NULL
```

Did you copy and paste your code? I think nothing is updating because you have IN NOT NULL rather than IS NOT NULL. (But if you just had a typo in your question, ignore this)

Comment: Thanks for the point. but that was just a typo. I edited